# Sending Binary 0 over socket connection in c#/.Net

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, binary

I am working on an application where I need to send a command over a socket connection and then receive the data it sends back.  I am having difficulty getting anything back from the server after sending my command.  I was told initially to "end the package with a binary 0", and I think this is what might be throwing me off as I am not really sure how to do this in c#.  Here is some source code:

```
    Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                sender.Connect(remoteEp);
                Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}", sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                byte zero = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("0")[0];

                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("PACK_ALARM.ALARM_GETCOUNTI,294,0" + zero);

                int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

                int bytesReceived = sender.Receive(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Test = {0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesReceived));

                sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                sender.Close();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Console.Write("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Socket Exception : {0}", se.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: You're sending *text* `0`, not *binary* `0`. Just send literal `0`. Or, since you're already sending a text, just add `\0` to the end of it.

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending a binary zero. You're sending the ASCII representation of the character `'0'`, converted to a number, converted to a string.

Instead, just do this:

```
byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("PACK_ALARM.ALARM_GETCOUNTI,294,0\0");
```

The `\0` is a literal for the null character - binary zero.

Also, note that TCP is a stream protocol, not a message-based protocol. You're supposed to keep `Receive`ing in a loop until you get the whole message. For short, infrequent messages, your code might work (unreliably), but any real communication is going to result in a horrible mess.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I changed my code to match what you suggested for the message string, but I am still not able to get past the receive method to the Console.WriteLine call. Even tho I am not yet looping, would I still get something back if this were working?  Also, to keep receiving until I get the whole message, would following the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126985/will-this-code-make-sure-i-read-all-i-want-from-a-socket help? Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Kyle You're probably doing something else wrong as well. Does `bytesSent` have the same value as `msg.Length`? Also, why are you using raw `Socket`s instead of `TcpClient`? As for the keep receiving part, yeah, that's the gist of it - however note that the poster of that answer assumes you know the size of the message to be received in advance. Since your case is a text-based protocol, it doesn't sound likely. Instead, you'll need to work with buffers, and (apparently) split messages by `\0`. It's a bit tricky, especially if you've never done something similar before.

Comment: @Kyle It's also quite possible there's an issue outside of your code as well - whenever you're doing any networking code, have something like Wireshark ready - you really want to see everything that happens on the line. You will be able to see whether your message went the right way to the right IP, and whether there was a response, for example.

Comment: I just stepped through my code again and bytesSent definitely has the same value as msg.Length.  I didn't really consider or even know that TcpClient existed.  I am assuming you recommend switching to using it? I have been doing c# development for the past several months, but have never tried to do any socket programming.  Do you have any recommendation on what the size of the buffer should be? @Luann

Comment: @Kyle `TcpClient` is a bit easier to use, especially when dealing with asynchronous I/O. Network programming is *hard* - you should probably read up a bit on the topic before you delve too deep; sadly, most tutorials and samples you'll find have serious flaws. Size of the buffer isn't a big deal, for a single connection you can use pretty much whatever - something like `4096` or `16384` will work fine. Do note that you can both receive just a part of the message, or multiple messages in one `Receive` (or `Read` on `TcpClient`'s `NetworkStream`). That's the tricky part about TCP :)