# c# Sockets Receive the full Data

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm still stuck at Tcp Sockets , i'm currently working on a Server/Client Project 
I'm Trying to receive the full Data that has been sent by the client but i don't get it all .

after some research , i get to know that `one Send doesnt surely mean one receive` , so i need to keep reading till the Buffer size hit the Size of the data sent .

```
    public void Connect()
    {

        try
        {
            _ThisSocket.Connect(this._HOST);
        }catch {}

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (_ThisSocket.Connected)
            {
                _ThisSocket.Receive(BufferSize, 0, 4, SocketFlags.None);
                int Size = BitConverter.ToInt32(BufferSize, 0);
                while (Size > 0)
                {
                    if (Size < _ThisSocket.ReceiveBufferSize)
                    {
                        _Buffer = new byte[Size];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _Buffer = new byte[_ThisSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
                    }
                    _ThisSocket.BeginReceive(_Buffer, 0, _Buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, Receive, _Buffer.Length);

                }
            }
        }
        ).Start();


    }

private void Receive(IAsyncResult AR)
{
    int Size = (int)AR.AsyncState;
    Byte[] buff = new Byte[Size];
    Array.Copy(_Buffer, buff, Size);
    String Data = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(buff);
    String Cmd = Crypter.Decrypt(Data);
    Switch(Cmd);

}
```

i m still new to c# Sockets programming , i excuse for any faults !

Comment: Take a look at this question I asked a few years ago, the answer gives some useful insight. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126985/will-this-code-make-sure-i-read-all-i-want-from-a-socket

Answer (score 1):

> This is an example I used the Socket class. example of receiving large
>   files and all data over sockets:

```
     private byte[] ReceiveLargeFile(Socket socket, int lenght)
     {
        // send first the length of total bytes of the data to server
        // create byte array with the length that you've send to the server.
        byte[] data = new byte[lenght];  


        int size = lenght; // lenght to reveive
        var total = 0; // total bytes to received
        var dataleft = size; // bytes that havend been received 

         // 1. check if the total bytes that are received < than the size you've send before to the server.
         // 2. if true read the bytes that have not been receive jet
         while (total < size) 
        {
            // receive bytes in byte array data[]
            // from position of total received and if the case data that havend been received.
            var recv = socket.Receive(data, total, dataleft, SocketFlags.None);
            if (recv == 0) // if received data = 0 than stop reseaving
            {
                data = null;
                break;
            }
            total += recv;  // total bytes read + bytes that are received
            dataleft -= recv; // bytes that havend been received
        }
        return data; // return byte array and do what you have to do whith the bytes.
    }
```

Comment: i need some explanation to fully understand

Answer (score 0):

there's no need to set the buffer size, this method bellow fits to response size:

```
public static byte[] ReceiveAll(this Socket socket)
{
    var buffer = new List<byte>();

    while (socket.Available > 0)
    {
        var currByte = new Byte[1];
        var byteCounter = socket.Receive(currByte, currByte.Length, SocketFlags.None);

        if (byteCounter.Equals(1))
        {
            buffer.Add(currByte[0]);
        }
    }

    return buffer.ToArray();
}
```